# PHP version from php-config not matched?

Tags: php, linux

I've manually compiled and installed PHP 5.3.8 on my Linux box but php-config gives me version 5.2.6. How can I change this? I need php-config to know the exact version. php -v gives me correct version 5.3.8.

```
php-config -h
Usage: /usr/local/bin/php-config [OPTION]
Options:
  --prefix            [/usr/local]
  --includes          [-I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr /local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib]
  --ldflags           []
  --libs              [-lcrypt   -lcrypt -lrt -lresolv -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 -lxml2   
  -lxml2 -lcrypt -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt ]
  --extension-dir     [/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613]
  --include-dir       [/usr/local/include/php]
  --php-binary        [/usr/local/bin/php]
  --php-sapis         [cli cgi]
  --configure-options []
  --version           [5.2.6]
  --vernum            [50206]
```

ls -s `which php` `which php-config`give me this:

```
25464 /usr/local/bin/php      4 /usr/local/bin/php-config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you didn't remove the old version of php before your compile install. Running:

```
ls -l `which php` `which php-config`
```

Should show you the time that the files were created, you might find that your compile/installed version didn't include php-config.

Comment: How I can include php-config with my compile? Is this a configure-option?

Comment: that's stupid. 'ls -s' just returns size of file in blocks, not version.

Comment: `ls -s` corrected to `ls -l`@shomeax, thanks for the constructive and grown-up "that's stupid" remark.

Answer (score 1):

try `php -v`  and check what it returns